# Need help disconnecting members if in a certain voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So with discord, I have made an AFK voice channel and set the server to if a member is AFK for 15 minutes, it sends them to the AFK voice channel. But I want to make it so my bot disconnects them from the channel straight away.

I've thought of two ways on how to do it, using intervals to check the voice channel every second, or to add a listener to if VoiceStateUpdate is the member being moved to the voice channel. I am trying to limit the amount of listeners in the main file so in the `client.once('ready', () => { })` I used an interval to check the voice channel every second.

```
setInterval(function () {
      const VoiceChannel = "718634068543012924"
  if(VoiceChannel.members.length > 0) {
    const now = new Date()
    const time = (`${now.getDay()}, ${now.getDate()}/${now.getMonth()}/${now.getFullYear()} ${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}`)
      member.voice.kick("AFK");
      console.log(`AFK Member kicked.`)
  }
  else {
      console.log("No one there bud.")
  }
}, 1000)
```

The problem is with the members.length , it comes with the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

I have tried .size and that still doesn't work, I don't really know what else to try or what I have done wrong, I have checked the discord.js.org documentation but I am still confused. So if there is any way to do this without adding another listener and you could help me that would be much appreciated. If not I will just suck it up and add one. Thank you.

Hermes

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the VoiceChannel as a string before the condition in your if statement is checked, causing the VoiceChannels.members property to be undefined.

Properly defining the varible containing the voice channel using your instance of the Client class should hopefully fix the issue:

```
setInterval(function () {
    const voiceChannel = <Client>.channels.cache.get("718634068543012924")
    if(voiceChannel.members.length > 0) {
        const now = new Date()
        const time = (`${now.getDay()}, ${now.getDate()}/${now.getMonth()}/${now.getFullYear()} ${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}`)
        member.voice.kick("AFK");
        console.log(`AFK Member kicked.`)
    } else {
        console.log("No one there bud.")
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: what is `clientObjects`? Is it equal to `new Client()`?. If so you should use `<Client>` to imply its an instance.

Comment: @Karizma https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client just an instance of this class. i'll update the answer to provide more clarification.

Comment: I see you have made an edit to the post so I'm guessing you realized I wasn't OP. Anyways you should note that `<Client>.channels` is not a collection in v12, it is instead `<Client>.channels.cache`, and lastly `<Collection>.get("id")` is more standard than `<Collection>["id"]`

Comment: I have tried your code and it gave me the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\lukel\Desktop\Boit remake\index.js:29:21)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)`
I'm assuming the defining voiceChannel didn't work as members is undefined :/

Comment: @Hermes Did you copy the code as is? Try defining the voiceChannel variable as `client.channels.cache.get("718634068543012924")`

Comment: Yeah I did try that and that is what I think is working. But now the problem is with the voice.kick . I use voiceChannel.members.voice.kick() and it comes with the error ` Cannot read property 'kick' of undefined`